# Email notifications when due date is approaching

Tags: trello

I'm somewhat new to Trello, so I'm simply not sure if this is an available feature.

Is there a way to set your Trello account so it sends an email to assigned members when a card's due date is approaching?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this card](https://trello.com/card/notifications-for-upcoming-due-dates/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1008) on the trello development board, this feature went live a couple of months ago.

> ### Notifications for upcoming due dates
>
> This will only be for cards to which you are subscribed or assigned.
>
> In notification email:
>
> There will be an "Upcoming Cards" section above the other
> notifications. It will include the cards that are within the
> "notification window" (default 24 hours). It will include the due date
> and time. It will be sorted by due date, soonest at top. If the user
> has seen the card in the upcoming section, it won't show the card
> again (the user will be included in the idMembersSeenUpcomingEmail
> field, or whatever it will be called). If the due date changes, it
> will reset that field.
>
> In notifications menu:
>
> Users will get a notification as the card enters the "notification
> window" saying when the card is due.
>
> Possibly include the ability to configure when reminder notifications
> are generated Possible option to remind every once in a while until
> it's due.